# ExtJS 3.4 when windows form show lost focus

Tags: extjs, focus, show, extjs3

I use ExtJS 3.4 with Ext.Window and textfield

when textfield keyup -> ExtWindowsVar.isVisible() false then ExtWindowsVar.show()

but textfield lost focus so i use setfocus and it works well

problem in here when i type korean '가' but it works like this 'ㄱ' -> LostFocus -> SetFocus -> 'ㅏ' Result is 'ㄱ ㅏ'